# how can I solve integrals including recursion of some sequences of functions

Tags: integral-equations, sequence

I would like to solve the equations as given below in mathematica. I have written some codes before but I have no idea when there is sub indexing to indicate the series of functions. I will be very happy and grateful if you could help me. Here are the equations:

$$P[n]=\int_{(-\infty,B)\cup (A,\infty)} q_n (x) \mathrm{d}x$$

and

$$q_n(x)=\int_{B}^A q_{n-1} (\omega)f(x-\omega)\mathrm{d} \omega,\quad q_1=f,\quad n\geq 1.$$
and $f$ is some density function, say standard Gaussian density. Eventually, I want to obtain the probability mass $P[n]$.

Thank you very much!

---

I wrote this (from Hector's post):

```
f0[x_] := 1/Sqrt[2*Pi*1^2]*E^(-(x + 1)^2/(2*1^2))
q[n_ /; n > 1, B_, A_, f_][x_] := NIntegrate[q[n - 1, B, A, f][ω] f[x - ω], {ω, B, A}]
q[1, B_, A_, f_][x_] :=f[x]
p[n_, B_, A_, f_] := NIntegrate[q[n, B, A, f][x], {x, -∞, B}] +              
                     NIntegrate[q[n, B, A, f][x], {x, A, ∞}]

N[p[1, -2, 2, f0[x]]] --> 0.160005
N[p[2, -2, 2, f0[x]]] --> 0.35594
N[p[3, -2, 2, f0[x]]] --> 0.237045
N[p[4, -2, 2, f0[x]]] --> 0.229432
N[p[5, -2, 2, f0[x]]] --> 0.222063
```

### ...

these results seem incorrect because $p$ is the probability mass function and should add up to $1$.

Correct results for $f_0$ Gaussian with mean $-1$ and variance $1$ and $A=2$ and $B=-2$:

```
n=1-->0.1600
n=2-->0.3559
n=3-->0.2323
n=4-->0.1238
n=5-->0.0633
n=6-->0.0320
n=7-->0.0162
```

Comment: You need the second line from my answer. That line ends the recursion defined in the first line.

Comment: Also, the function must be a pure function (the type that uses `#` as the variable). I will update my answer to make it work numerically and with functions defined the way you do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since OP seems to be interested in numerical calculations, this might be more suitable:

```
f0[x_]:= 1/Sqrt[2*Pi*1^2]*E^(-(x + 1)^2/(2*1^2))

q[1, A_, B_, f_] := f

q[n_ /; n > 1, A_, B_, f_][x_] :=
  Module[{ω},tempIntegrate[Evaluate[q[n - 1, A, B, f]][ω] f[x - ω], {ω, A, B}]]

p[n_, A_, B_, f_] :=
    tempIntegrate[q[n, A, B, f][x], {x, -∞, B}] + 
     tempIntegrate[q[n, A, B, f][x], {x, A, ∞}] //. {
      s_ tempIntegrate[a_, b__] :> tempIntegrate[s a, b], 
      tempIntegrate[tempIntegrate[a_, b__], c__] :> tempIntegrate[a, b, c] } /.
   tempIntegrate -> NIntegrate
```

Then, as a test case, `p[3, -2, 2, f0]` evaluates to `0.73581`.

---

**Original answer**

The subindices are really parameters. One way to do it is to include the parameters along with the variables (see how Mathematica does it for the [Legrendre polynomials](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LegendreP.html) for example). Subindices could also be part of the head of the function, for example `f[a][x]` can be thought of as the function $f_a(x)$.

The code you need is as below. Note that `A` and `B` are also parameters (and that I changed their order respect to your post).

```
q[n_ /; n > 1, A_, B_, f_][x_] := Integrate[q[n - 1, A, B, f][ω] f[x - ω], {ω, A, B}]
q[1, A_, B_, f_][x_] := HoldForm@f[x]
p[n_, A_, B_, f_] := Integrate[q[n, A, B, f][x], {x, -∞, A}] +
     Integrate[q[n, A, B, f][x], {x, B, ∞}]
```

I included a `HoldForm` to check whether the recursion is correct. The following input

```
p[2, 1, 3, Exp[-#^2] &]
```

produces

[image]

You might want to erase "HoldForm@" from the code above to get the actual answer. That is, change the second line to

```
q[1, A_, B_, f_][x_] := f[x]
```

Now, depending on the function `f`, Mathematica might take a long time to answer if you leave those integrals in analytic form. You might want to replace `Integrate` by `NItegrate` if you are interested in a numerical approximation.

Comment: what does the sign '#' mean?

Comment: It is the parameter of a pure function. Note that the final answer depends on what is the density function `f`. So, you need to supply it. In the example, `f[x]=Exp[-x^2]`.

Comment: You need to localize the variable in the integral `Module[{ω}, Integrate[...]]` should do it

Comment: I tried the codes you posted. Although the codes seem correct, I was not able to get $P[n]$. I want to plot it an have some feeling what is going on with the computations but I cannot get it. I only need some numerical values for $P[n]$. What should I do?

Comment: Please see the code part which i appended to my question. Still I dont get any value.

Comment: okay I tried it. as you said it is working. Thank you very much. I learned some new things..

Comment: @ssch Nice catch, thank you (+1)

Comment: The code unfortunately doesnt produce correct results for a Gaussian example. I will update the code part i used and I will give the outputs in my question. A colleague of mine has a matlab implementation and it works. I will also post the correct results as well.

Comment: Okay the code part above works fine. p[6, -2, 2, f0] gives 0.0320212. But I changed all "A" to "B" and all "a" to "b" in the code. I guess there is a little confusion there. It still takes alot of time and gives many errors. Is it possible to skip the errors? or making the code less fine so that it is faster?

Comment: p[8, -2, 2, f0] is like a hell, I still wait for a result.