# Recursive Integral for Volume of $n$-Ball

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, recursion

The volume of an $n$-ball (the $(n+1)$-dimensional analogue of a disk) of radius $r$ can be found by the following integral recurrence:
$$V_0(r)=2r$$
$$V_n(r)=\int_{-r}^rV_{n-1}\left(\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\right)\ \mathrm{d}x$$
I would like to use Mathematica to compute a few terms of this recurrence (as an exercise. I am aware that an explicit formula exists). The recursive code I came up with was this:

```
BallVolume[dimension_, radius_] := If[dimension == 0,
  2*radius,
  Assuming[radius > 0,
   Integrate[
    BallVolume[dimension - 1, Sqrt[radius^2 - x^2]],
    {x, -radius, radius}
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

Calling `BallVolume[1, r]` works as expected, giving $\pi r^2$, but Mathematica seems to get stuck when evaluating `BallVolume[2, r]`. This doesn't seem to be a problem with its ability to integrate; if I define explicitly `CircleArea[r_] := Pi*r^2`, then `Integrate[CircleArea[Sqrt[r^2 - x^2]], {x, -r, r}]` correctly gives $4 \pi r^3\over 3$. Why does the above code fail for dimensions $3$ and higher?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are using the same dummy variable for all integrals.

---

**Extended answer**

Modify your code slightly and note that all integrals use the same dummy:

```
BallVolume[dimension_, radius_] := 
 If[dimension == 0, 2*radius, 
  Assuming[radius > 0, 
   testIntegrate[
    BallVolume[dimension - 1, Sqrt[radius^2 - x^2]], {x, -radius, 
     radius}]]];
BallVolume[2, r]
```

[image]

Use `Module` to create temporary dummies.

```
BallVolume[dimension_, radius_] := 
 If[dimension == 0, 2*radius, 
  Assuming[radius > 0, 
   Module[{x}, 
    Integrate[
     BallVolume[dimension - 1, Sqrt[radius^2 - x^2]], {x, -radius, 
      radius}]]]];
BallVolume[3, r]
```

I learned about this issue thanks to a comment by ssch in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32514/8803).

---

Recursive functions are suitable for memoizing. That has the advantage of not having to perform those integrals over and over again.

```
hBallVolume[d_Integer /; d > 0] := 
  hBallVolume[d] = 
   Function @@ {r, 
     Integrate[hBallVolume[d - 1][Sqrt[r^2 - x^2]], {x, -r, r}, 
      Assumptions -> r > 0]};
hBallVolume[0][r_] := 2 r;
```

[image]

Comment: Hello. I'm working in your last solution (recursive function). I'd like that $d$ was considered a variable rather than a parameter, that is, that hBallVolume was a function of two variables $d$ and $r$, so that I could see how hBallVolume depends on $d$ for a fixed value of $r$ besides how hBallVolume depends on $r$ for fixed values of $d$. How could I do it? It's driving me crazy. (I'm a beginner in Mathematica). Thank you.

Comment: @drake: $d$ is already a variable: `dimension`. If you want a general formula, you can induce one yourself (that would be beyond this question). Try `Table[BallVolume[d,r],{d,4}]`. Better yer, try `Table[hBallVolume[d][r], {d, 10}]`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for a closed formula. I have asked it as a separate question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37632/explicit-closed-formula-for-recursive-integral-as-a-function-of-the-recurrent-p

Answer (score 7):

```
vol[n_]:=FullSimplify[
 Nest[Integrate[# /. r -> Sqrt[r^2 - x^2], {x, -r, r}] &, 2 r, n], 
 Element[r, Reals] && r > 0]
```

The results can be tabulated for :

```
 Style[TableForm[Table[{Subscript[V, j + 1], j, vol[j]}, {j, 4}], 
  TableHeadings -> {None, {"Sphere volume", "n", "volume"}}], 20]
```

[image]

Comment: If the purpose is to get a table, use `NestList` instead of `Nest`.

Comment: @Hector excellent point...