# Explicit, closed formula for recursive integral as a function of the recursive parameter

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, recursion, difference-equations

This is a follow-up of this [question/answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33931/recursive-integral-for-volume-of-n-ball/33936#33936).

I'm working on a recursive integral more complicated than the one on the linked question, but this one can be used as an example.

I would like to obtain a closed expression for the dependence of the integral on the dimension $d$, that is, on the recursive parameter. In other words, I want to know what the general term of the recurrence relation is. `RSolve` is not able to find it (in my example).

Answer (score 2):

Using [@ubpdqn's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33937/193) for getting a closed expression for the dependence of the integral on the dimension **n**.

```
vol[n_] := vol[n] = FullSimplify[Nest[Integrate[# /. r -> Sqrt[r^2 - x^2], {x, -r, r}] &, 2 r, n], 
                                                                      Element[r, Reals] && r > 0]

FindSequenceFunction[Table[vol[n], {n, 1, 6}], n]
(*
 (π^((1 + n)/2) r (r^2)^(1/2 (-1 + n)) (r - (-1)^n r + (1 + (-1)^n) Sqrt[r^2]))/(2 Gamma[(3 + n)/2])
*)
```

I don't quite understand your sentence *"I want to know what the general term of the recurrence relation is"*, since that is exactly what @ubpdqn used.

Comment: Thanks. The general term is the one you wrote between (* *), that is, the term as an explicit function of $n$. Unfortunately, FindSequenceFunction does not work for my recurrence relation. Any idea? Should I write my specific recurrence relation?

Comment: @drake 1) Keep in mind that it isn't always possible to find a closed form 2) Post it in another question, as this one would radically change , and that isn't convenient