# n-fold convolution

Tags: convolution

I am trying to calculate n-fold convolution of a function as
$G^{*n}(x)$ where $G(x)=1-a*exp(-b)+b*ln(b)$.

I tried this function, Convolve[G[x], G[x]^{n - 1}, x, x] but it didn't give any answer.
Could you please help me on this matter? Is there any way to calculate n-fold convolution of a function in mathematica?

Comment: have a look at my question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32505/how-can-i-solve-integrals-including-recursion-of-some-sequences-of-functions may be others can know. What I khow is either taking the fourier transform, multiply and transform back, or, calcuate it iteratively as in my question above.

Comment: thanks @seyhmusGüngören, I'm trying it.

Comment: What are `a` and `b` in `G[x]`?  Also, please display literal Mathematica code in questions whenever possible, like `G[x_] := 1 - a Exp[-b] + b Log[b]`.  Doing so will attract more answers.  I suggest you edit your question now.

Comment: Not hearing back from you, I tried `G[x_] := 1 - x Exp[-x] + x Log[x]` and got no answer too.  This was because Mathematica just kept running, burning more and more memory.  I aborted it to avoid crashing.  The problem probably is the `x Log[x]` term, which is singular at `x = 0`.  `x Exp[-x]` probably has a similar problem at negative infinity.

Answer (score 1):

First, `Convolve` only works when the output variable is different:

```
Convolve[Exp[x], Exp[-x^2/2], x, x]
```

won't work, but

```
Convolve[Exp[x], Exp[-x^2/2], x, y]
```

does, resulting in

```
E^(1/2 + y) Sqrt[2 Pi]
```

Your second problem is that $G(x)$ is not actually dependant on $x$, it is merely a constant.  The convolution of two constant functions is infinite or undefined, so it makes sense that Mathematica won't return any output.

A third problem is that your syntax for derivatives is incorrect (assuming by $f^{*n}$ you mean $f^{(n)}$, the $n$-th derivative of $f$).  `G[x]^(n-1)` raises `G[x]` to the `n-1` power.

However, you wrote `G[x]^{n-1}`; in Mathematica, curly braces (`{}`) are used to define lists, not to group like in $\TeX$.  Since `Power` threads over lists, the result is `{G[x]^(n-1)}`, a list with a single element, `G[x]^(n-1)`.

You want to use the derivative function `D`:

```
D[G[x], {x, n-1}]
```

Lastly, you'll need to define `G` before using it, so that Mathematica knows what you're talking about.  The command

```
G[x_] := 1 - a Exp[-b] + b Log[b]
```

defines `G` as your original expression.  Note that you'll want to modify it to depend on `x` for the convolution to make sense!

Comment: Sorry for the delay and thank for all your comment. In the meantime, I have been working on the function G(x). You are right. The latest version of the G(x) function is $G(x)=1-exp(-x)+x(-a-ln(x)+Gamma[0,x]+log(x))$. I need to calculate $G^{∗n}(x)$ where  $$G^{*n}(x) = \underbrace{G(x)*G(x)*G(x)* \cdots*G(x)*G(x)}_n,\quad $$ Is it possible in mathametica?